# How to change old dependency code to new dependency code?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using below dependencies in my flutter web app with firebaseAuth and firestore:

```
  firebase_core: ^1.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.3
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
```

Below are the script versions on web/index.html:

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

I want to navigate the screen to screen after user login with the credentials. I am tiring below method but its not working. Unable to use then `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.then((user) {` and .getDocuments() `.where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid).getDocuments()` How to solve this.
Actually, I want to open the admin screen after get the user role saved in firestore user data. So in this case, User id of current user which is logged in should be match to uid field in a document stored in firestore. And then it should be match the role with the role field. For reference please find the images.

I am trying below code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webfire/admin_screen.dart';
import 'package:webfire/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class UserManagement {

  signOut() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  //FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  
  authorizeAdmin(BuildContext context)  {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.then((user) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
          .getDocuments()
          .then((docs) {
        if (docs.documents[0].exists) {
          if (docs.documents[0].data['role'] == 'admin') {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => const AdminScreen()));
          } else if (docs.documents[0].data['role'] == 'user') {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => const HomeScreen()));
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Below is Cloud Firestore data Image:
[image]

I am using email and password authentication. User id and the uid in firestore are same. you can find below image.
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any specific error message after running the code? If yes, please mention the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Please see the added image. Its showing red underlines.

Answer (score 0):

- `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is no longer `Future<User>` it's direct `User?` object
- After where condition use `.get()` function to get Snapshot

Comment: Okay. Can you give me any Example Code. Or can you please edit my code.

Comment: I don't the structure please check this document  https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/